# Is posible proof that there is not a holomorphic function $f:\Delta\rightarrow\bar{\Delta}$, such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(z)=i$ for some $z\in\Delta$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have problems with this:

Proof that there is not a holomorphic function $f:\Delta\rightarrow\bar{\Delta}$, such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(z)=i$ for some $z\in\Delta$.

My problem is that I am getting very few conditions on $\Delta$, ie it can be any set, I understand that at least contains the $0$ and $z$ mentioned, but I think you need more information, have proof or counterexample to the given conditions?

Comment: What is $\triangle$?  It must be defined somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Schwarz lemma that says that $f:\Bbb D$->Cl$( \Bbb D) $ is holomorphic $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for every $z\in \Bbb D$. Thus $|f(z)|\leq |z|$ fore every $z\in \Bbb D$

Here,$i$ is not in $\Bbb D$ and $|f(z)|=|i|=1$ which contradicts the lemma that says $|f(z)|<1$

Answer (score 0):

$\Delta$ is most likely the interior of the unit disc.

Answer (score 0):

The open mapping theorem says that $f(\Delta)$ is open.  What can you do with that?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(z_0)=i$ for some $z \in \Delta$ then $z$ is an interior point of $\Delta$ and $|f(z)| \leq |f(z_0)$ for all $z \in \Delta$. But this contradicts the maximum modulus principle.